# Derivative of $\det(XAX^H)$ wrt $X$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I found the following derivative in the Matrix cookbook [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) (equation 570):
$$
\frac{\partial  \det(XAX^H)}{\partial X} =  \det(XAX^H)\left(AX^H(XAX^H)^{-1}\right)^T
$$
is this correct or should we use Hermitian instead of Transpose?
I mean
$$
\frac{\partial  \det(XAX^H)}{\partial X} =  \det(XAX^H)\left(AX^H(XAX^H)^{-1}\right)^H
$$

Comment: In the case of 1-by-1 matrices the first RHS is $\bar{X}$ while the second is $X$, which is incorrect, so atleast the second modification may be ruled out

Comment: The question does not make sense. $\det(XAX^H)$ in general is not complex differentiable. E.g. in the scalar case, when $A=1$, $\det(XAX^H)=|X|^2$ is differentiable only at zero.

Comment: The formula is for the Wirtinger derivative (i.e. it treats $X^H$ as independent of $X$). So the formula with the transpose, not the Hermitian conjugate, is correct for that interpretation. This approach is sometimes called the [CR-Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835).